# Suggestion box hiding behind the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, autocomplete

In my project, there is a autocomplete search textbox. Whenever the user is typing something the suggestion box will appear just below the textbox. This suggestion box is hiding behind the screen.

I tried to get in front by applying largest possible `z-index`, still no use.

[Here is the link to the site.](http://www.edgefxkits.com/android/)

I am providing my site link because the jsfiddle is working fine.

For testing purpose, type `co` in the textbox and see how the suggestion box is visible.

Comment: Why does the suggestion box have to be hiding behind, can't it just be hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

search for this code and change 12 to 9 .. solve the problems

```
.edgefxContentContainer {
top: -16px;
z-index: 9;
}
```

change this div class style :

```
<div class="edgefxContentContainer pRelative">
```

Comment: Nice one.. this also explained me how z-index behaves... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `.edgefxContentContainer` contains a z-index of 12. This reveals some of the suggestion box parts. Suggest you search for z-index and debug it

Comment: Also, .edgefxHeader has a z-index of 10. Taking that out seems to fix it.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question instead @ChadHedgcock suggestion worked for me.. anyway, thanks to both of you :)

Comment: @ChadHedgcock I am still confused why the child container was depending on the `z-index` value of one of the parent container i.e `edgefxHeader`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Mr_Green This is how z-index works. If I have a <div parent z-index=10><div child z-index=1></div></div>, you should look at this as the z-index of child is 10.1 (not 1), so the child will never be in front of the parent. See this article, helped me a lot with z-index http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/