# Style jQuery autocomplete results

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

This is how the autcomplete shows results now.[image]
It is behind the search-bar. Is it possible to bring it above. Also, I want to style it. Can somebody give some style references.

Below is the code for header-container

```
.header-container {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
background-color: #1E1E1E;
width: 100%;
z-index: 2000;
height: 42px;
}
```

And this for search input:

```
#header-search-input {
background-image: url(images/search.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-size: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
color: #424A61;
border: none;
font-size: 14px;
height: 22px;
width: 355px;
position: absolute;
top: 9px;
overflow: hidden;
right: 40%;
padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Comment: can u provide some code or ur web url

Comment: Some code would be helpful with figuring out a potential issue.

Comment: We'd love to see the code as well. Did you try setting `z-index`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397594/suggestion-box-hiding-behind-the-screen/21398197#21398197 -- check my solution here

Comment: maybe you can play with z-index and top .. it hard to figure error without actual web or JSFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**style it:**

```
input#autocomplete { 
 /* styles here */
}
```

**z-index:** *(It would be optimal to use z-index properly to prevent other problems along the road with the stacking of your elements)*

Understanding `z-index` and stacking order.

- http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index
- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fixed it by altering the z-index to 2 as suggested by airi. Though, I don't really got how it fixed the problem.